# quick sort by hoare partition in r

Tags: r, sorting

I worked on quicksort by hoare partition in rstudio. I find some codes on http://rosettacode.org/wiki/Sorting_algorithms/Quicksort#Julia
There they use *Julia* and I test them and they work fine. But when I translate them into *r.script*, the sorting programming doesn't work. ( I also translate them in *python* and program works, so I suppose codes are correct). I try to sort A=[-3,3,-4,2,0], the code in r is following:

```
quicksort = function (A,i,j) {
   if (j>i){
     pivot = A[i]
     left=i
     right=j

    while (left <= right) {
      while (A[left] < pivot) {
        left=left+1
           }
      while (A[right] > pivot) {
        right=right-1
           }
      if (left <= right){
        temp=A[left]
        A[left]=A[right]
        A[right]=temp
        left=left+1
        right=right-1
         }
    }
    quicksort(A,i,right)
    quicksort(A,left,j)
  }

  return (A)
}
```

I got sorted result as [-4,3,-3,2,0], it seems that the program just skip the recursion parts and do the sorting just one time. Can anyone tell me why it doesn't work in r?

Comment: This was more a of code hunting exercise, but your problem seems to be here: `pivot = A[i]` ... `while (A[left] < pivot) {` This `while` loop is never triggered as A[i] = A[left] = pivot.

Comment: R, unlike Julia or Python, passes all primitives (including arrays) by value. So this function is not in-place, unlike the Julia version. The answer by @CactusWoman is correct.

Answer (score 3):

Simply calling `quicksort(A,i,right)` doesn't do anything. The function does not mutate the object you pass into it. Instead, change these lines so you are assigning the output to `A`:

```
A = quicksort(A,i,right)
A = quicksort(A,left,j)
```